# How should I display the result using HTML <table> tag in columns of 50 records each(except the last column)?

Tags: php, html, for-loop, if-statement, html-table

I've written a program which currently generates 540 different numbers.

I want to display these 540 different numbers in a columns having 50 records each(except the last column where the number of records should be less than 50) using HTML `<table>` tag but I'm not able to do so as there are so many loops and conditions are getting applied.

Following is my program :

```
<?php
function findFourElements() { 

    $possible_numbers = '';

    $sr_no = 0;

    $row_count = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {

        for ($j = 0; $j <= 9; $j++) {

            for ($k = 0; $k <= 9; $k++) {

                for ($l = 0; $l <= 9; $l++) {

                  $possible_numbers[0] = $i;
                  $possible_numbers[1] = $j;
                  $possible_numbers[2] = $k;
                  $possible_numbers[3] = $l;

                    if((int)$possible_numbers[0] + (int)$possible_numbers[1] + (int)$possible_numbers[2] + (int)$possible_numbers[3] === 14) {
                        $sr_no++;
                        echo $sr_no. ') ' . $possible_numbers[0].$possible_numbers[1].$possible_numbers[2].$possible_numbers[3]. '<br>';                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}

findFourElements(); 
?>
```

Please somebody help me out with my logic.

Comment: How many rows and columns do you want to print?

Comment: @RohitRasela : I want 11 columns with first 10 columns having 50 records(i.e. rows) each and the 11th column having 40 records(i.e. rows). Each of these columns should have two sub-columns having headings 'Sr. No.' and 'Vehicle No.'. If you run the code I've given as it is you will be able to get the 540 distinct nos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
<?php 
function findFourElements()
{

    $response = [];

    $possible_numbers = '';
    $sr_no = 0;

    $row_count = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {

        for ($j = 0; $j <= 9; $j++) {

            for ($k = 0; $k <= 9; $k++) {

                for ($l = 0; $l <= 9; $l++) {

                    $possible_numbers[0] = $i;
                    $possible_numbers[1] = $j;
                    $possible_numbers[2] = $k;
                    $possible_numbers[3] = $l;

                    if ((int)$possible_numbers[0] + (int)$possible_numbers[1] + (int)$possible_numbers[2] + (int)$possible_numbers[3] === 14) {
                        $sr_no++;
                        $response[] = $possible_numbers[0] . $possible_numbers[1] . $possible_numbers[2] . $possible_numbers[3];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $response;
}


$response = findFourElements();

$data = array_chunk($response, 50);

$srNo = 1;
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ($data as $key => $value) { ?>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Sr. No.</th> <th>Vehicle No.</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php foreach ($value as $val) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $srNo ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $val ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php $srNo++; } ?>
                </table>
            </td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

if you don't want to work with return response you can add extra code inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a while statement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
<?php

/** Calculations
(# = amount)
540/50 = 10.8   (# of rows)
50*0.8 = 40     (# of records in last row)
*/
echo "<table>";


    $x = 0;
    $ranNum = 0;
    echo "<tr>";

        while ($x < 540) {
          /* a round number (1,2,3,4,5,...) %1 = 0.
          So (Number/50)%1 is only 0 if it's in the multiplication table of 50*/
          if ((($x/50)%1) == 0) { 
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
          }
          $ranNum = rand(1000,9999); // random number
          echo "<td id='Track".$x."'>".$ranNum."</td>";
          $x++;
        }

    echo "</tr>";


echo "</table>";
?>
  </body>
</html>
```